# How to log a colored message with Yeoman?

Tags: yeoman, terminal-color

I have tried `console.log('message')`, but it returns the message in black.

Is there a way to log a message in color in a generator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the same color module [Chalk](https://github.com/sindresorhus/chalk) as used by the generator system to colorize your text.

First install it:`npm install --save chalk`

Then:

```
var chalk = require('chalk');
this.log(chalk.bold.yellow('message'));
```

Comment: Thanks Sindre, its perfect.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the color in the output, such as when using gulp and other modules that already provide their own colors?

Comment: You can also do `this.log(chalk.bold.yellow('message'));` within a yo method.

Answer (score 3):

For new users viewing this question `console.log();` should "never" be used in Yeoman, according to the [Documentation](http://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html). Instead use `generator.log();` mainly seen in practice as `this.log()`.

> To allow for this flexibility [of running in various user interfaces, not just in terminals], Yeoman provides a set of user interface element abstractions. **It is your responsibility as an author to only use those abstractions when interacting with your end user.** [Emphasis added.] Using other ways will probably prevent your generator from running correctly in different Yeoman tools.
>
> For example, it is important to never use `console.log()` or `process.stdout.write()` to output content. Using them would hide the output from users not using a terminal. Instead, always rely on the UI generic `this.log()` method, where `this` is the context of your current generator.